# Typescript :How import from source code instead file

Tags: angular, typescript

I use this snippet :

```js
  loadComponent(name) {
    var url = this.configurationService.configuration.api_url+"/generator/dynamic-loading/component/"+name;
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(componentCode => {
      let result = ts.transpile(componentCode);
      console.log("### Component",result);
    });
  }
```

and i wouldlike "import *name* from *result*"

How it is possible ?

Comment: is this what you want ?    `  let  {name:result}= ts.transpile(componentCode);`

Comment: i download ts code of a component and i want import component in my application after transpile code

Comment: Can you explain bit more

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, `result` is the JavaScript source code of a module (which I'll call the "dynamic module"), and you want to load this module and access its exports.  Assuming that there is a fixed, small list of modules that the dynamic module is allowed to import, it's probably easiest to transpile the dynamic module to CommonJS format and write a mini module loader that sets up the proper context to `eval` the JavaScript source code.

```
function evalCommonjsModule(moduleSource: string, requireMap: Map<string, {}>) {
    let moduleFunc = eval("(module, exports, require) => {" + moduleSource + "}");
    let module = {exports: {}};
    moduleFunc(module, module.exports, (requireName) => {
        let requireModule = requireMap.get(requireName);
        if (requireModule === undefined)
            throw new Error(`Attempted to require(${requireName}), which was not in requireMap`);
        return requireModule;
    });
    return module.exports;
}


import * as AllowedImport1 from "allowed-import-1";
import * as AllowedImport2 from "allowed-import-2";

// In loadComponent:

// Example from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-simple-transform-function
let result = ts.transpileModule(componentCode, {
  compilerOptions: { module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }
});
let resultModule = evalCommonjsModule(result, new Map([
    ["allowed-import-1", AllowedImport1],
    ["allowed-import-2", AllowedImport2]
]));
let name = resultModule.name;
```

If the imports of the dynamic module are not restricted to a short list known in advance, then your options will depend on the module bundler or loader that you are using for the main project.  Since `loadComponent` is asynchronous already, if your bundler/loader supports dynamic import, then you may be able to transpile the dynamic module to AMD format and have your mini-loader perform dynamic imports of all the dependencies of the dynamic module before loading its body.  There may be existing libraries that can help with this, but I'm not familiar with them; others should feel free to add information about them.